# How to add a row to non-unique table class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been reading up here on stackoverflow and I think I get how to add a row to table using jQuery.

```
$('.myTable').find('tbody:last').append('WHATEVER CODE');
```

That way seems to work fine, but now I realized that I have two (or more) tables with the same class, so when I add something it becomes visible in both tables.

How do make sure it only adds a row to the first, last or fourth table?

Thanks for your time.

BIG EXCUSE ME! Ok, for whatever it is worth, I made the mistake of writing ID because I took the example code from another question. I know you can only have one unique ID - that's a given. Sorry, sorry, sorry... Again, I'm sorry.

Comment: ID:s should be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, of course the tables use class, I just took the example from another question. In my case, the tables use class.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? There's no reason to vote it down...

Comment: If the tables use classes, but have unique ids, then use their IDs to select them uniquely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the filter() function.

```
$('table.yourclass').filter(':first') // first of matched tables
$('table.yourclass').filter(':last') // last of matched tables
$('table.yourclass').filter(':eq(2)') // 3rd matched table
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3):

"The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document)"

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 2):

There are no excuses for having more than one element of one id. That is the only reasonable answer to that question, disregarding the fact that there may be workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you want ID:s to be unique.

If you want to select a table by its index you could do something like:

```
var tableIndex = 1;

$('table').eq(tableIndex).append('<tr></tr>');
```

If you want to select a range:

```
$('table').slice(1, 4).append('<tr></tr>'); //selects the second and third table
```